# time data '(datetime.date(2021, 7, 30), )' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, python-datetime

I am accessing date from database using below query, in my jupyterLab notebook:

```
newDate = con.cursor()
newDate.execute("select max(CalendarDate) as cdates from db.table1 where cdates < getdate()")
c_date = newDate.fetchone()
cDate = str(c_date)
current_date = datetime.strptime(cDate,'%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(currentdate)
```

it is giving this ValueError:
time data '(datetime.date(2021, 7, 30), )' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'

can anyone guide, the correct way pls?

Comment: Why this? `cDate = str(c_date)`? You are trasforming a date into a string( `"(datetime.date(2021, 7, 30)"`). Just keep your date, and format the output

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it seems the query output is coming in the form of 'pyodbc.Row'. When directly formatting, getting this error: AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'strftime'.

Comment: print it, print the `type(c_date)`, and try to understand what you get. (before your `str`). The problem is there, and you are trying to avoid it, but then it will hit again (the error you get in the title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `c_date` is already a datetime.date object. You don't need to `cDate = str(c_date)`.

try:

```
newDate = con.cursor()
newDate.execute("select max(CalendarDate) as cdates from db.table1 where cdates < getdate()")
c_date = newDate.fetchval()
current_date = c_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(currentdate)
```

Comment: this is the issue, when i go like this , i'm getting AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'strftime'.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem now is with fetchone(), try replacing it with fetchval().